# How can I add a preview for an MP3 on a Facebook post without Soundcloud?

Tags: facebook, music

I use Soundcloud to add  a preview for an MP3 on a Facebook post:

[image]

How can I add a preview for an MP3 on a Facebook post without Soundcloud so that the user doesn't have to open a new tab to listen to the MP3?

Comment: Doesn't the Play button work on that thumbnail for you? Tested it and it will load a player within the window.

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise Sometimes it does but sometimes it open a link to SoundCloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has removed this feature since then: it is not possible anymore to preview an MP3 without Soundcloud.